# SCCM 2012 R2 Remove-CMDevice

Tags: powershell, sccm

Greeting Everyone,

Hoping someone has a quick insight but I am getting access denied on a service account using the PowerShell command Remove-CMDevice.
This process is as per outlined here, https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj821759(v=sc.20).aspx

The account has permission to remove devices from SCCM and this works fine through the GUI but not the command line. I have been unable to find documentation on what permissions the account need to do this via command line, it works fine manually in the GUI.

If anyone can shed light on this it will be wonderful, I do want to keep this service account as having as minimal permissions as possible.

Many thanks,

Edit to Add Image as follows, 
[image: PowerShell Output from SCCM Console]

Comment: I would like to see the error returned from PowerShell console. The permission is the RBA permission. As you can use this account to remove from console, the RBA permission should be OK. Keep in mind, the account is not a 'service account', just a normal admin account.

Comment: Hi FrankDong, I have edited the above to add image of this output. Thanks. Keeping in mind this works fine from GUI, just not PoSh

Comment: The error message clearly show that it's permission related, the account running and connecting to PowerShell for Configuration Manager console needs to have RBA permission on the mentioned device. If it's OK to do it via Admin console, then there must be something corrupted and what I suggest is to delete the admin account from Console and then re-add it. Please backup related security role permission and re-create it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a lot of testing, I'm here with an answer on the **Permission** part when using PowerShell console to remove CM system object. Of course the symptom is the same: The account can delete from Admin console, however, when using PowerShell, it failed with Permission error message.

The account to perform the *Remove-CMDevice* cmdlet must have proper **RBA Permission** on the object. Assume the security scope is default one, the account connected to Configuration Manager console must have below RBA permission which I tested is almost **minimal** permission:
[image]

In the screenshot the **Collection** part, the permission is easy to understand, **Read**, **Delete Resource**, etc.

For the **Computer Association** part, you may get confused, why?

**Steps I did the troubleshooting:**

I opened a PowerShell Console connecting to Configuration Manager using my test account and run below command to see what will happen:

```
Remove-CMDevice 'Rsuraceccc' -Verbose
```

I got below error:
[image]

Yes, it's trying to querying from the *SMS_StateMigration*. Then I try to run a simple command:

```
Get-WMIObject -NameSpace root\sms\site_clt -Query 'Select * from SMS_StateMigration'
```

Once again, I got error. So I get the conclusion that the account needs Permission on *SMS_StateMigration*. So I add **'Recover User State'** permission of **Computer Association** on the role and tried again, cheers, this time all command runs successfully.

I don't know why it's using *SMS_StateMigration*, but this is the case here.

Comment: Thanks FrankDong, with some testing this is now working based on your solution. I had to add the permission 'SITE \ Read' to be able to use the scriptblock sent to SCCM server but this is otherwise 100%. Many thanks for your assistance and work on this, have a great day

Comment: I'm happy it helped you:)